# Contra- and Co-variance - CLR via C#

Tags: .net, covariance, contravariance

In the CLR via c# third edition there is an example that I cant seem to make sense of:

> Invariant Meaning that that generic
>   type parameter cannot be changed. I
>   have shown only invariant generic type
>   parameters so far in this chapter. n
>
> Contravariant Meaning that the generic
>   type parameter can change from a class
>   to a class derived from it. In C#, you
>   indicate **contravariant** generic type
>   parameters with the **in keyword**.
>
> Contravariant generic type parameters
>   can appear only in input positions
>   such as a method’s argument. n
>   Covariant Meaning that the generic
>   type argument can change from a class
>   to one of its base classes. In C#, you
>   indicate **covariant** generic type
>   parameters with the **out keyword**.
>   Covariant generic type parameters can
>   appear only in output positions such
>   as a method’s return type.

The author then goes on to give this example:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```

> Here, the generic type parameter T is
>   marked with the in keyword, making it
>   contravariant; and the generic type
>   parameter TResult is marked with the
>   out keyword, making it covariant

Here is where I run into the issue on the following page(292) he then goes on the say the opposite when using an interface.

> When using delegates that take generic arguments and return values, it is recommended to
>   always specify the in and out keywords for contravariance and covariance whenever >possible,
>   as doing this has no ill effects and enables your delegate to be used in more scenarios.
>   Like delegates, an interface with generic type parameters can have its type parameters be
>   contravariant or covariant. Here is an example of an interface with a contravariant >generic
>   type parameter:

```
public interface IEnumerator<out T> : IEnumerator {
Boolean MoveNext();
T Current { get; }
}
```

> Since T is contravariant, it is possible to have the following code compile and run >successfully:

```
// This method accepts an IEnumerable of any reference type
Int32 Count(IEnumerable<Object> collection) { ... }
...
// The call below passes an IEnumerable<String> to Count
Int32 c = Count(new[] { "Grant" });
```

In the second example he uses the out key word (`IEnumerator<out T>`)  and then calls it contravariant. Is this correct or am I missing something. Is there a difference defining a contravariant & covariant in an interface? [I have been to Oreilly's website regarding this book and this is not listed.](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780735627048)

Comment: It's important to note that the design of `Delegate.Combine` is fundamentally incompatible with variance.  If a routine has an initially-null field of delegate type `Action<Cat>`, and it tries to `Combine` it with an `Action<Animal>`, the field of type `Action<Cat>` will hold a reference to an `Action<Animal>`.  If one then tries to `Combine` that with an `Action<Cat>`, the attempt will fail.  For this reason, delegates types which may ever be used with `Combine` should not be covariant nor contravariant.  It's too bad delegate types don't define their own `Combine` methods, since...

Comment: ...a method `Action<Cat>.Combine` could have safely taken the `Action<Animal>` and converted it to a type `Action<Cat>`, knowing that the result of such a conversion would only be used by code which would feed it a `Cat`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`out` = **covariant** and `in` = **contravariant**.

Any words to the opposite are a mistake in my book which I'll correct in a future edition.

Comment: You do know you've just checked into the developers' version of the Hotel California, right?

Comment: Pink champagne on ice, anyone?

Comment: Just goes to show you can't judge a user by their reputation!

Answer (score 9):

That's a mistake. It's definitely an example of covariance. There's no difference in meaning of covariance and contravariance between delegates and interfaces.

I suggest you email O'Reilly to report the error.

Comment: Or the author will come and answer directly... `:)`

Comment: @Justin: Well yeah, that's always an option ;)